# Building Static Version Of React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading through the React documentation, and they recommend that you build out a static version of your app first. Here is a direct quote:

> The easiest way is to build a version that takes your data model and
>   renders the UI but has no interactivity. To build a static version of your app that renders your data model, you’ll want to build components that reuse other components and pass data using props.

Its not 100% clear to me how I would implement this in an efficient manner. I am not new to React, but have not followed this specific approach before, and would like to try.

My thought was that I use mock data, and pass those down as props to other components as I build out the app. For example, lets look at a real component I will be building, called "Patients". Ignore the JSON format, it will be in regular JS object notation in the real app.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const patients = [
  {
    "profileId": "b4KEOLTxPcu73VVc",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "birthDate": "1994-10-10T04:00:00.000Z",
    "gender": "M",
    "email": "john@doe.com",
    "provider": "ckdj8g9isusjx765",
    "__v": 0,
    "verified": false,
    "status": "ARCHIVED",
    "lastActive": "2018-03-13T02:17:38.391Z",
    "profileCreatedAt": "2018-03-13T02:17:38.391Z"
  }
]

export default class Patients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="patients">
        <PatientsTabNavigation />
        <PatientsSortableTable  patients={patients} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Is this what they mean when they talk about passing your data model down as props? Once you have all this stuff built out for all your components in your application, then are you supposed to loop back and then hook up all these components to Redux and implement your AJAX calls?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your understanding is correct that you first make single component and then reuse it again.
To add to your example for better clarification-
Let's just say `<TableRow>` is the component which you are using to render single table row then you would do something like in your `PatientsSortableTable` class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class PatientsSortableTable extends Component {
    render() {
        const patients = this.props.patients.map((patient) => <TableRow patient={patient}/>)
        return (
            <div>
                {patients}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and in you TableRow it could be a stateless component like:

// assuming your patient is an object with these keys

```
export const TableRow = (props) => {
    const { name, age, gender } = props.patient
    return(
        <div>
            <div>{name}</div>
            <div>{age}</div>
            <div>{gender}</div>            
        </div>
    )
}
```

so assuming you have some big patients list so you will be reusing `TableRow` component

Comment: Is this how you would go about building an app? Using mock data, then hooking up any ajax calls?

Comment: yes, this is how i would approach after making a `fetch` call